# connecting pgAdmin4 docker to postgres instance- server dialog not showing

Tags: postgresql, docker, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I'm new to docker and pgAdmin.

I am trying to create a server on pgAdmin4. However, I cannot see the Server dialog when I click on "Create" in pgAdmin. I only see Server Group (image below).

Here's what I'm doing in the command prompt:

Script to connect and create image for postgres:

```sh
docker run -it -e POSTGRES_USER="root" -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD="root" -e POSTGRES_DB="ny_taxi" -v "c://Users//bpatel//data-engineering-zoomcamp//week_1_basics_n_setup//2_docker_sql//ny_taxi_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data" -p 5431:5432 postgres:13
```

Script to run pgAdmin after postgres is running:

```sh
docker run -it -e PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL="admin@admin.com" -e PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD="root" -p 8080:80 dpage/pgadmin4
```

I am using `localhost:8080` in my browser to open pgAdmin. When I try to create a new server, I only see "Server Group" option. But I need the "Server" dialog. Image for reference:

[image: Screenshot of pgAdmin]

I'm not sure what I am missing? Please help! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They recently changed "create server" to "register server", to more accurately reflect what it actually does.  Be sure to read the docs for the same version of the software as you are actually using.